# MVC localhost doesnt work after disabled IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

After disabled IIS, my MVC project which are using localhost that used to work is not longer working. Whenever i try to access the database, it will come out an error. Then i decided to create a new mvc project to test again but same problem still occur. Here is the error message displayed when i trying to access the localhost database.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.
>   )

I had found a lot solutions but none works on mine. Can anyone help me solve the problem? 
Btw, i am using Visual Studio 2015 and Window 10.

Comment: check this [Why am I getting “Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci)

Comment: hi, thanks for reply. But it still didnt solve my problems. Actually my computer cant find "SQL Server Configuration Manager" as they mentioned. Thus i dunno where is the mistake that i made. But my mvc project used to works before i disabled IIS and install Xampp. After thats, everything goes wrong.

Comment: open web config of your application, using the credentials in connection string try to connect the database using sql server interface

Comment: it still cant solve my problem

Comment: @AhHui Check this [Link](https://gerardbeckerleg.wordpress.com/2015/07/08/visual-studio-2015-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql-server-the-server-was-not-found-or-was-not-accessible-verify-that-the-instance-name/)

Comment: @Webruster thanks for reply. but still didnt solve my problems.

Comment: post ur webconfig where your connection string resides and also some code

Comment: [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7rv1sj17t6rff3r/Testing.zip?dl=0)
this is the link to download my project. This project works in my home laptop but it doesnt work in my company's pc. Thanks